# How to make sure I load the JS file just once in my partial?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, partials

I have a partial *_dial_pad.html_erb* which is being loaded through Ajax calls more than once at the same view, using something like:

```
$('#some_div').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: 'dial_pad')) %>");
```

The dial_pad partial contains:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'dial_pad' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "dial_pad" %>

<center>
  <div id="main-wrapper" >
    <section role="main">
      <div class="dialPad compact">      
        <div class="dials">
          <ol>
            <li class="digits one">
              <p><strong>1</strong></p>
            </li>
            <li class="digits two">
              <p><strong>2</strong></p>
            </li>
          </ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <br/>
  </div>  
</center>
```

The dial_pad.js.coffee looks something like:

```
jQuery -> 

  $(document).keydown (e) -> 
    key = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)    

    if key=='1'
      alert("1")

    if key=='2'
      alert("2")
```

Now when dial_pad partial loaded the dial_pad js loaded as well. So I ended up pressing 1 as for example and the alert triggered twice.

How can I make sure the dial_pad.js is loaded just once and not whenever I add the partial for the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a window property when it is loaded and then check that property before you bind the keydown.

```
jQuery ->

    unless window.dialPadIsLoaded
        window.dialPadIsLoaded = yes

        $(document).keydown (e) -> 
            key = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)    

            if key=='1'
                alert("1")

            if key=='2'
                alert("2")
```